# How do I block reels on Instagram?

Tags: instagram, parental-control, focus, productivity, digital-wellbeing

I find myself wasting lots of time watching Instagram reels that I did not intend to watch. It is not good for me and does not help me achieve the goals I want to achieve. I have installed tools to help me limit the time I spend on certain activities on my smartphone and on my laptop, but now I'm looking for a tool to do this with Instagram reels in particular.

Is there a way to block Instagram reels completely on the Instagram app on my Android phone?

Comment: On Firefox or Kiwi browser, this is easy. Use Ublock Origin extension and block the elements responsible for loading those reels. On the app, this is going to be pretty hard. I tried to block the reels on Facebook app by first investigating whether the reels are fetched from a source which could be distinguished from the rest of the data the app fetches. It did not help. Other solution was to decompile the app and look for the code that adds those reels. Well, FB app's code was massive and was minified on top of that, so I gave up investigating it.

Comment: @Firelord wow! Thanks for going to all that effort. I didn't realise you could log on to Instagram in your web browser on mobile, I thought Instagram forced you to use the app on mobile.